# What is the minimum software needed to Build a React Native Hello World APK on Windows 7

Tags: android, windows, reactjs, react-native

OK so I'm trying to find what I have to install to be able to create an APK from the react native hello world tutorial on a Windows 7 PC.

Specifically I'm just trying to make an APK of the hello world code. No real functionality yet based on:

"Create React Native App is the easiest way to start building a new React Native application. It allows you to start a project without installing or configuring any tools to build native code - no Xcode or Android Studio installation required"

So far I have

1. nodejs 7.10.1 (to avoid NPM 5)
2. JDK 9.04 (to create a keystore file)

I have the hello world app running by way of using notepad to edit the app.js file and using a web browser or the expo client app to run it.

The hello world introduction at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html mention just running "gradlew assembleRelease" but the command doesn't work with an out of the box nodejs/NPM install.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html has instructions for native code with 4 things to install (Node, Python2, JDK, Android Studio) but I'm assuming I can crate a non native code app?

So my question boils down to: Is it possible to make an APK of the hello world code without installing the entire development environment needed for native code? If so what else to I need to install?

Comment: I guess docker should be helpful here. https://github.com/adambene/react-native-android

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Expo](http://expo.io/)

Best way to start a projetc without installing all the native environement. You will need a simulator (genymotion is free) or a real device. The setup is really easy to do.

Comment: I already mentioned the expo client. But how does that help me create an APK? I have several real android phones to run the app(s). But as far as I can see Expo is about the development process not the deployment process.

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/publishing.html this link should help you. Expo help you from dev process to deployement.

Comment: no, that is no help. It relies on WSL which only exists for Windows 10. As I said in the main question I'm looking for a solution that works on Windows 7.